# How to call another module controller's method in multi module spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, maven-3

I have spring boot project with two module, Below is the project structure

```
MultimoduleApplication
-------pom.xml
-------login
          pom.xml
          MainApplication
          LoginController

-------Customer
          pom.xml
          CustomerController
```

LoginController like this

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLogin() {
        return "Welcome to login module";
    }
}
```

And CustomerController like this

```
@RestController
public class CustomerController {

    @GetMapping("/getCustomer")
    public String getCustomer() {
        return "Welcome to customer module";
    }
}
```

I run login module because main method include into login module.
after maven clean and install and successfully we run spring boot application

try to hit below url into browser

```
http://localhost:8080/login

we got response like **Welcome to login module**
```

But when we call  http://localhost:8080/getCustomer
we are getting error like

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Oct 03 18:44:29 IST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Since the main module is login module I am getting success response form loginController but when I call url of CustomerController unable to get response.

How can I fix it ?
Your help is save my day!

Comment: You have to add the the package of the CustomerController to your `component-scan`

Comment: BTW: I wouldnt  name the path `"/getCustomer"` more `"/customer"`.

Comment: The Customer module probably needs to be added as a dependency to the login module.  Or, have a third module, name something like WebApp, move `MainApplication` to the WebApp module, and add Customer and login modules as dependencies.

Comment: @Jens I have tried add this line into main application class @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.multimodulecustomer.customer") but still not getting any success :(

Comment: Can you share the package names, the pom.xml and the `MainApplication` class